# Selecting specific columns from dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks this this:

```
A   B   X50_TT_1.0  X50_TT_1.1  X60_DD_2.0  X60_DD_2.1  X100_L2V_7.0    X100_L2V_7.1
3   1       1           0           0           1          1               0
6   3       0           1           0           1          0               1
2   3       1           0           0           1          1               0
10  5       0           1           1           0          1               0
0   0       1           0           1           0          0               1
```

I want to have new data frame (df) which only contains columns which ends with 1.1, 2.1 i.e.

```
df

X50_TT_1.1  X60_DD_2.1  X100_L2V_7.1
0              1            0
1              1            1
0              1            0
1              0            0
0              0            1
```

As here I only shows few columns but actually it contains more than 100 columns. Therefore, kindly provide the solution which can be applicable to as many columns dataset consists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe subset every 2nd column? `df[, 3:ncol(df)][, c(FALSE, TRUE)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the pattern is, that the column ends on ".1" may you need to adapt it at that point.
My data I am using

```
    original_data
  A B X50_TT_1.0 X50_TT_1.1 X60_DD_2.0 X60_DD_2.1 X100_L2V_7.0 X100_L2V_7.1
1 3 1          1          0          0          1            1            0
```

Actually this is for everything ending with "1"

```
df <- original_data[which(grepl(".1$", names(original_data)))]
```

For ending with ".1" you have to use:

```
df <- original_data[which(grepl("\\.1$", names(original_data)))]
```

For `original_data` both gave me the same result:

```
    df
  X50_TT_1.1 X60_DD_2.1 X100_L2V_7.1
1          0          1            0
```

Comment: You don't need to use `which` here.

Comment: Oh thank you, actually I was not sure about this, thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminMohn Thanks!!